# CSS ignore width of one child element

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists

I have an HTML Menu which consists of list items and sub menus:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#navi {
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
#navi > ul {
  right: 0;
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#navi > ul li {
  text-align: right;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
#navi > ul li,
#navi > ul li * {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
}
#navi > ul li ul {
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
```

```html
<div id="navi">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>top level a</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <li>
            <a>a sub level a</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a>a sub level b</a>
          </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>top level b</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a>b sub level a</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want the submenu to be horizontal underneath the top level menu. The submenus should appear on hover and be positioned with the parent list item element.

All the hiding and displaying stuff is done and my menu works except one issue.

I want the submenu (`ul`) to **not** effect the width of the parent element so that the top menu items lay next to each others and the submenu expands below.

I would need to tell the `li` element to base its width on the first child (`a`) and ignore the width of the submenus `ul` element.

Also I don't want to use JavaScript or similar, a plain CSS solution would be gorgeous!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: it would be really helpfull if you can post a fiddle too..

Comment: I will see what I can do, the CSS is a bit complex, will take a bit to extract the necessary code.

Comment: ya that would be better..i think.. :) :)

Comment: Saves us having to do the complex work!

Comment: @Lal Please encourage users to use inbuilt stack snippet rather than posting the code via external links...

Comment: I added a snippet. I hope I didn't forget any essential CSS, but it looks quite complete

Comment: @TJ: Of cause I use the built-in solution ;)

Comment: @Julian *"All the hiding and displaying stuff is done and my menu works except one issue"* - The hiding stuff isn't working in the demo..? :/

Comment: I didn't include it, because it not strong related to the question. That would be just `display:hidden/block;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positioning the sub-menu absolutely does what you want.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v3xLkvke/1/

Commenting out the position attribute will change the width of the containing `li`.

Comment: But how do I handle the problem of the first / last element? The sub-nave could stand out on the left or right edge... This cannot be done with pure CSS, right? Maybe flex or something?

Comment: Yeah sure, but it would not auto align the second and next to last element. I'm pretty sure there is no pure CSS solution for ensuring the elements do not stand out.

Comment: One notice: The `ul` is (with `position:absolute;`) sticks to parent `li`s left edges level. When I do `let/right:0;` the position is not related to the parent `li`. How is that related?

Comment: No, horizontal submenu is what it should be like. Just not standing out. I think I'll need a JS solution :/